# How to use Madgwick filter

Tags: filter, accelerometer, gyroscope

There is data from the gyroscope and accelerometer:

```
gyro_xyz = [gyro_x,gyro_y,gyro_z]
acc_xyz = [acc_x,acc_y,acc_z]
```

There is an implementation of the Majwick filter on Python:
[Madgwick filter](https://github.com/morgil/madgwick_py/blob/master/madgwickahrs.py)

I create an object:

```
angles = MadgwickAHRS()
```

I push the data into the object:

```
angles.update_imu(gyro_xyz,acc_xyz)
```

What's next??
Explain how to use the Medjwick filter in a Python script if I need to get angles along the X, Y, and Z axes in degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert the quaternion to euler angles by using the Quaternion class method `to_euler_angles()`

```
rpy = angles.quaternion.to_euler_angles()
print("rpy: ", rpy)
```

hope it answer your question